# What is the entropy of a call to java.lang.Math.random()?

Tags: java, random, entropy

[`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) produces a `double` value (IEEE 754 binary64) in the range [0.0, 1.0). How many digits (or bits) of entropy does the return value of `random()` contain?

If it simplifies things, I'm okay with assuming the distribution is a true uniform random distribution - in which case I'm essentially asking how many unique values are contained in a `double` in [0.0, 1.0).

(Sorry in advance if this question is off-topic - wasn't sure where to ask.)

Comment: You are aware that `Math.random()` is not cryptographically secure, right?

Comment: Consider editing the word "entropy" out of the question. It sounds like you misunderstand the term and mean something else. (Or you misunderstand the concept and you're about to do something very dangerous.)

Comment: If you’re really asking about entropy, it’s a trick question. The answer would be zero - the algorithm it uses is completely deterministic. Math.random is useful only for statistics, not crypto.

Comment: @forest Yes, I am. I'm scoring submissions for a security experiment, and some participants used `Math.random()` instead of `SecureRandom` to generate an access token. I would like to include the entropy of the key as part of the scoring.

Comment: @JohnDeters Is the entropy of a single call to `Math.random()` actually zero even we assume the engine is initialized with a suitably random seed? (Maybe that's too strong an assumption?)

Comment: The first call will have the uncertainty of the seed. The second call should reveal the internal state. Subsequent calls should then be 100% predictable.

Comment: You might need more than two. This paper recommends 7-10. https://yurichev.com/writings/SAT_SMT_by_example.pdf

Comment: @JohnDeters If people used `Math.random()` to generate a secure access token, you should fail them. That is a major no-no in information security.

Comment: @forest , this is not my question, but I agree that using Math.random() for a cryptographic purpose is a cardinal sin, and that failing the test is a completely appropriate response (assuming the students were properly instructed against it. )

Comment: @forest There were many major no-nos committed in the study.  However, I'd still probably rate a solution that uses an improper key higher than one that used no key at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The representable values of any floating point scheme including 754 are never uniformly spaced. The values returned by `Math.random` and equivalently `Random.nextDouble` *are* uniform in the range [0,1) but are only a small fraction of the `double` values in that range.

The Java-default `Random` never has entropy over 48 bits and depending on seeding can be less, and as forest commented it doesn't even try to be secure -- techniques for breaking an LCG (Linear Congruential Generator) given a few outputs have been known for decades. In contrast there are very nearly 2^62 `double` values in the stated range.

Comment: That's helpful, at least as an upper bound. I also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0/2979032#2979032) for the number of values in [0, 1].